# Eclipse-RCP keyboard-shortcuts only work after user pushes corresponding menu item

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently migrating an Eclipse RCP 3.1 application to Eclipse 4.2, which works well so far. Because the application is very old, there are no commands, and the old concept of actions is still in use. The custom keyboard-shortcuts work fine, but there are three shortcuts that make trouble: **save**, **undo** and **help**. For those shortcuts I had to introduce the concept of commands:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
        <key sequence="CTRL+S"
            commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"/>
        <key sequence="CTRL+Z"
            commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow"/>
        <key sequence="CTRL+H"
            commandId="org.eclipse.ui.help.helpContents"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"/>
    </extension>
```

Now those shortcuts are in conflict with Eclipses own shortcuts.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-04-25 10:08:11.263
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-04-25 10:08:11.263
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+S:
Binding(CTRL+S,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.file.save,Save,
        Save the current contents,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.file,File,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@7ef7f414,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+S,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.file.save,Save,
        Save the current contents,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.file,File,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@7ef7f414,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
    ...
```

Changing the key-bindings of Eclipse for **save**, **undo** and **help** doesen't work. When pushing **CTRL+H** for the first time, the search dialog opens. Pushing it for the second time, the help finally opens.
Those three shortcuts only work if the user first executes those actions through the menue entries. After that, the shortcuts work.

I don't understand this behaviour. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why define them again when Eclipse has already defined them?